# Getting 'isLoading' state undefined in react query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query, tanstack

After I updated react query to the latest version, I am getting undefined for 'isLoading' state when using useMutation. Here is the code:

```
const useAddUserNote = (owner: string) => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { mutate, error, data, isLoading } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (note: CreateNoteData) => addUserNote(note),
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(["allUserNotes", owner]);
    },
  });

  if (error instanceof Error) error;

  return { mutate, data, error, isLoading };
};
```

Here is the type error

`Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type 'UseMutationResult<any, Error, CreateNoteData, unknown>'.`

When I console log the 'isLoading', it is undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the API reference for your version. In the [latest documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/reference/useMutation), `isLoading` no longer exists -- it appears to have been removed after [version 4](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useMutation).

This is also [explicitly called out in the upgrade guide from version 4 to version 5](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#status-loading-has-been-changed-to-status-pending-and-isloading-has-been-changed-to-ispending-and-isinitialloading-has-now-been-renamed-to-isloading). Make sure to read these when you upgrade!

You should update your code to use `isPending`:

```
const { mutate, error, data, isPending } = useMutation({
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help! Apparently, I have looked at the wrong place :)

Comment: It caches the versions u have been looking for. Due to this i never looked into he version tab :)